# kafka increase session timeout so that consumers will not get the same messsage

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Java app that consumes and produce messages from kafka.
I have a threadpool of 5 thread, each thread creates a consumer and since I have 5 partitions the job is decided between them.

i have a problem that 2 threads are getting the same message since the hearthbeat doesn't comes to the broker since each message processing takes about an hour.

I tried to increase the session.timeout.ms in the broker and also changed the group.min.session.timeout.ms so that the max value will allow it. 
In this case the consumer cannot be started.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Kafka version are you running? Since [version 0.10.1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3888), the Java consumer sends heartbeats in a background thread, so long message processing would not trigger a consumer group rebalance.

Answer (score 0):

The keep alive is not sent so thats not true as far as it seems